# Android apps that record sound and remove background noise

Tags: android, voice, recorder

i want to know the android apps that can record voice and would not record the background noise . eg in room a person is talking the voice of that person is recording while the noise of fan or other thing is not recording .

Comment: Pretty much every phone out there (at least the ones I've worked with) will perform noise suppression when you record audio. How well they succeed will vary from product to product (depending on the algorithm used, the form factor, number of mics, mic placement, acoustic calibration, etc). Your bet bet may be to use the `VOICE_RECOGNITION` AudioSource. Even though the CDD states the no noise suppression should be used for this source, many OEMs / platform vendors actually do the opposite and apply aggressive noise suppression to get as clean a speech signal as possible.